# post ID from array ( $post->ID )

Tags: wordpress

The get_post returns the post ID as an array `( $post->ID )` with multiple values. I need post id of particular post, how to extract this?

Answer (score 0):

you are using the correct function for this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post

if you were using get_posts(); , then that would return multiple ID's, but using get_post would only return an object or array containing a single post. e.g.:

```
<?php
$my_post_id = 20;
$my_post = get_post($my_post_id); 
$title = $my_post->post_title;
?>
```